# Where do I place the .egg (Python)?

Tags: python, egg, zope.interface

I'm trying to install the zope interface script for Python. However, the only download I saw was a .egg file type. I'm running Windows Python 2.7, where should I place this file for the Zope interface to work properly with my Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, if you're like me and have an irrational hatred of the python egg cache and how poorly it handles effective user ids, install the egg unzipped via:

```
easy_install -Z zopepackage.egg
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have easy_install, simply run:

```
easy_install zopepackage.egg
```

If you don't have that, you could also just unzip the .egg and copy the created zope/interface directory in your site-package directory, although this is not the best way.

(In my Windows install, I find a `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\zope\interface\` directory)